Ubuntu Ruby install failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/-----
After this operation, 42.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu. co m/ubuntu noble/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.015-1
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-13build1
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.015-1
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-13build1
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.015-1 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 libncurses6 amd64 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 javascript-common all 11+nmu1

it basically says this for everything after IGN17, im on Ubuntu 24.04. 
it doesnt allow me to include the whole output so i made a screenshot. including version information.
ofc i already tried the suggestions at the end and trying to change my dns to 8.8.8.8 . im basically dont anything baout this stuff so please dont be too harsh on me

Always best to include all info in a question. This looks like the output of some question but the question is missing. Please edit the question and put in the complete details. Also please cut and past the contents of the sources list into the question, not as a comment.The version of Ubuntu is missing from your question as well.

Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' usually means some kind of network problem - either your DNS service is misconfigured, or is unreachable due to some other network error
